# Fixed position sidebar does not adjust to different resolutions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My web page is http://lyk-ag-stefan.att.sch.gr/.
You may see the blue sidebar at the left which is fixed positioned since I want its content to be always visible. The problem is in small resolutions e.g. 1024x768 where some of the bottom content is not visible. How may I always adjust the whole sidebar content to any viewport?

Also, I have two queries:

1) Does it make sense to assign floating to a fixed positioned div?

2)By giving a 21% percentage width to sidebar, it calculates the 21% of body width (not the 21% of 1200px of its grandparent width); so far so good since it gets out of the normal flow. The strange point is  it takes into account the 7% margin-left of its grandparent(content-wrapper) which is subtracted from body width as to find the 21%. Why that?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Your best shot would be to use viewport width instead of a percentage, to do so, first of all set the viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

And then instead of setting the width of 21% to the sidebar, set it to 21vw which will be 21% of the viewport width.